# How do I display multiple constants in html?

Tags: javascript, html, display

I have 1 constant called people with data about two people with many sub-attributes like name, weight, height, stats, etc. How do I display this in html?

```js
const people = [
    { 
        name: "person 1", 
        height: 100, 
        weight: 100, 
        stats: [
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "hp",
                }
            },
                {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "attack",
                }
            },
                {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "defense",
                }
            },
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "special-attack",
                }
            },
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "special-defense",
                }
            },
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "speed",
                }
            }
        ],
        types: [
            {
                slot: 1,
                type: {
                    name: "something"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "person 2",
        height: 100,
        weight: 100,
        stats: [
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "hp",
                }
            },
                {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "attack",
                }
            },
                {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "defense",
                }
            },
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "special-attack",
                }
            },
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "special-defense",
                }
            },
            {
                base_stat: 100,
                effort: 100,
                stat: {
                    name: "speed",
                }
            }
        ],
        types: [
            {
                slot: 1,
                type: {
                    name: "something"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to print it. If you want to print it as it is try the below approach. Below code uses [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with some spacing provided in third argument. Make sure to use html `pre` tag to display it.

If you want to show only some data from the object, use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to iterate the object and extract the data you want. Once you have the data, you can show it in HTML as you like.

```js
const people = [{
    name: "person 1",
    height: 100,
    weight: 100,
    stats: [{
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "hp",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "attack",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "defense",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "special-attack",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "special-defense",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "speed",
        }
      }
    ],
    types: [{
      slot: 1,
      type: {
        name: "something"
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "person 2",
    height: 100,
    weight: 100,
    stats: [{
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "hp",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "attack",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "defense",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "special-attack",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "special-defense",
        }
      },
      {
        base_stat: 100,
        effort: 100,
        stat: {
          name: "speed",
        }
      }
    ],
    types: [{
      slot: 1,
      type: {
        name: "something"
      }
    }]
  },
]

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(people, undefined, 4);
```

```html
<h1>JSON pretty print in HTML</h1>
<pre id="container"></pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make a loop in Javascript and iterate each object in array

```js
const people = [ { name: "person 1", height: 100, weight: 100, stats: [ { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "hp", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "attack", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "defense", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "special-attack", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "special-defense", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "speed", } } ], types: [ { slot: 1, type: { name: "something" } } ] }, { name: "person 2", height: 100, weight: 100, stats: [ { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "hp", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "attack", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "defense", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "special-attack", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "special-defense", } }, { base_stat: 100, effort: 100, stat: { name: "speed", } } ], types: [ { slot: 1, type: { name: "something" } } ] }, ]
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  text += people[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: This provide an easy way to get loop in javascript